# If $S(t)=-1200\cos(\frac{\pi}{6}t)+1500$ and $C(t)=1200(1.025)^{t}$, then how many times does $S(t)=C(t)$, for $t > 0$?

Tags: trigonometry, exponential-function

> The population of Summertown varies according to the model $$ S(t)=-1200\cos\left(\frac { \pi  }{ 6 } t\right)+1500 $$ The population of Cool Ridge varies according to the model $$
> C(t)=1200(1.025)^{ t }
> $$
>   In both models, $t$ represents the number of months since January 1, 2004. Based on these models, how many times after January 1, 2004, will $S(t)=C(t)$?

Is there a quick way to find out without using a graphing calculator?

Comment: Yikes! Indeed it has about 15 solutions ...

Comment: Hi and welcome to MSE. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Comment: @ThomasLesgourgues Hi! Sorry I've updated my question accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, then I guess we must retrict $t$ to be a positive integer. Or could we have a non integer $t$?

Comment: @MattiP. I've added some context to my question, could you please take another look? Thanks!

Comment: @ThomasLesgourgues I'm not so sure, but I've copied the question verbatim. The question itself seems a little vague, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First show that the function $C(t)$ is strictly increasing from $C(0)=1200$.

Then the function $S(t)$ is sinusoidal with minimum at $300$, maximum at $2700$ and period 12. That means that it's strictly increasing on $(0,6)$ then strictly decreasing on $(6,12)$ and so on.

On each of these intervals, by the Intermediate value theorem, the function $S(t)-C(t)$ must be equal to $0$ exactly once, **until** $C(t)$ grows too big (larger than the max of $S(t)$ i.e $2700$).

You need the value of $t$ such that $1200(1.025)^t=2700$, this is given by 
\begin{align}
(41/40)^t&=\frac{2700}{1200}=\frac{9}{4}\\
t &= \frac{\ln(9/4)}{\ln(41/40)}\\
\end{align}
If you have access to a basic calculation, this yields $t\approx 32.8$

Therefore we will have $C(t)=S(t)$ exactly once on each of the intervals $(0,6)$, $(6,12)$, $(12,18)$, $(18,24)$, $(24,30)$ and $(30,36)$, hence 6 times.

**Edit** Note that this works because the last interval on $(30,36)$ is decreasing, otherwise we would have to look at in details.